# Caesar Cipher in Python, command line options, decrypt problem

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

below the code for a Caesar cipher, I had to do.
The list of characters, which has to be wrapped around hast to start with the lowercase alphabet and then the uppercase characters (so 52 letters in the list, first 26 letters are the lowercase then the Uppercase; if a is encrypted with a shift of 26 it becomes A..).
The code only has to work with small shifts (that's the assignment)!

You can see the command-line options: it has to be done this way!

My problem is, that some letters in a sentence i encrypt first don't decrypt correctly afterwards, whereas all the other letters decrypt correctly (as far as I can see, encryption works properly).

I think I had it working, but then tried to tweak a little to get it working for large shifts (which didn't work properly: so this would be my second question: how would you do it?[but it's not necessary for the assignment]) and must have messed up something and can't find the error!!!

Pls help, have I made a small error I overlook or was it wrong from the beginning?
(I'm quite the newbie as you can see :) ).

Thank you very much

```
import argparse

import string


#parser

def parse_args():
    #create command line argument parser object
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser('Caesar Cypher')
    
    
    parser.add_argument('--msg', '-MSG', action='store', help= 'message to be encrypted/decrypted',type=str, default='Hello World!')
    
    parser.add_argument('--decrypt', action='store_true', help='turn on decryption mode', default=False)
    
    parser.add_argument('--shift', '-SHIFT', action='store', help='shift characters by SHIFT positions',type=int, default=4)
 
    return parser.parse_args()
 
#functions

def shift(msg, shifted: int):
    
    #list  lower upper alphabet
    as1=string.ascii_lowercase
    as2=string.ascii_uppercase
    al=list(as1+as2)
    
    for char in msg:
        
        if char.isalpha():
            
            #char's new index is 
            crypted_index=(al.index(char)+shifted)%len(al)
            

            
        
            #encrypted letter
            crypted_char=al[crypted_index]

            #replace letter with crypt
            msg=msg.replace(char, crypted_char)   
    
    return msg

def decrypt(msg, shifted: int):
    
    #list  lower upper alphabet
    as1=string.ascii_lowercase
    as2=string.ascii_uppercase
    al=list(as1+as2)
    
    for char in msg:
        
        if char.isalpha():
            
            #char's new index is 
            crypted_index=(al.index(char)-shifted)%len(al)
            

            
        
            #encrypted letter
            crypted_char=al[crypted_index]

            #replace letter with crypt
            msg=msg.replace(char, crypted_char)   
    
    return msg

#main function

if __name__ == '__main__':
            
    #parse cmd line args
    args=parse_args()
    
  
    
 
        
    #backwards shift decrypt
    backshift=args.shift if not args.decrypt else args.decrypt
    
    #shift
    crypted_cypher=shift(args.msg, backshift)
    
    print(crypted_cypher)
```

Comment: `msg=msg.replace(char, crypted_char)` this is not the way to do it. You should simply create a new string and add the character to it. Currently you are replacing a character, but that new character may be considered plaintext by the next call to `replace`. Don't be hasty ;) By the way, usually you are supposed to shift lowercase to lowercase and uppercase to uppercase. This also works, but it is just not common (and you now have a weak key on the middle index (26)).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast answer, I really appreciate the clarification! I didn't expect such a fast answer and 'repaired' the script by using a 'table' instead of the whole char replacement business :) Haha, I was supposed to do it like that.. With a weak key you mean, 'cause it helps decryption to see the upper/lower change?

Comment: It's a Caesar cipher, the value 26 will just change the case and leave the plaintext otherwise intact.

Comment: haha, yeah of course, you're right, can't use 26 here :)